# Получить последнюю запись

Tags: laravel, eloquent

У меня есть три таблицы

1. users
2. passports
3. sections

Мне необходимо получить перечень всех пользователей с их паспортаными данными, но необходимо получить данные только актуального паспорта(последнный выданный, колонка passportDate)

Структура таблиц:
USERS

```
Table 
            ...
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('section_id')->nullable()->constrained();
            ...
```

Section

```
Table
            ...
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            ...
```

Passport

```
Table

            ...
            $table->date('passportDate')->nullable();
            $table->string('firstName')->nullable();
            $table->string('middleName')->nullable();
            $table->string('lastName')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            ...
```

Нужен массив записей со следующими полями:

```
 "email" "section_title"  "firstName"  "middleName" "lastName"
```

Мой вариант запроса:

```
$users = User::select('users.*', 'sections.title', 'passports.firstName', 'passports.middleName', 'passports.lastName')
                            ->leftJoin('sections', 'sections.id', 'users.section_id')
                            ->leftJoin('passports', 'user_id', 'users.id')
                            ->orderBy('user_id')
                            ->get();
```

Проблема в том, что у пользователя может быть несколько паспортов, в таком случае мой запрос дублирует записи о пользователе. Если в базе у пользователя 5 паспортов, я получаю массив с 5 записи этого пользователя.
Подскажите как исправить запрос для моей задачи.

Comment: и почему вы юзаете чистые джойны а не отношения моделей?

Comment: мне необходимо получить список всех пользователей. Нет идей как решить это через отношения.

Answer (score 0):

$users->passports->last()

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]